# Append new XML Node to an existing XML in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: xml, jenkins, groovy

I have the following XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<testsuites>
  <testsuite name="xray" tests="2" failure="0" timestamp="2023-07-07T05:25:33.339Z" skipped="0" failure-evaluating="0">
    <testcase name="SPT-4323" classname="testim.io.test" time="52.597" ownedBy="Staysure Automation" ownerEmail="automationteam@staysure.co.uk">
    </testcase>
    <testcase name="SPT-4331" classname="testim.io.test" time="20.823" ownedBy="Automation Team" ownerEmail="nipunam@intervest.lk">
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Looking for a solution to add following node in to "testcase" node

**Node to add**

```
<properties>
  <!-- using a custom "test_key" property -->
  <property name="test_key" value="SPT-4323" />
</properties>
```

I was trying following script in Jenkins pipeline and it was appending the node, but throwing an error.

```
stage('Update_XML') {
  try {
    def File = readFile "${env.WORKSPACE}/testim-tests-report.xml"
    echo "${File}"
    def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(File)
    def xrayIDs = xml.testsuite.testcase.collect {
      it.@name
    }

    echo "Xray IDs are ${xrayIDs}"

    def toadd = ''
    '<properties> <
    property name = "test_key"
    value = "SPT-4323" / >
      <
      /properties>'''

    fragmentToAdd = new XmlSlurper(false, true).parseText(toadd)

    xml.testsuite.testcase.appendNode(fragmentToAdd)

    String outxml = groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
    echo "Output XML ${outxml}"

  } catch (Exception) {
    build_status = false
    echo Exception.toString()
  }
};
```

**Error in Jenkins console**
[image]

Comment: You're parsing the xml into a variable `xml`, and then you're trying to parse it again with `def root = new XmlSlurper( false, true ).parseText( xml )`

Comment: @tim_yates Thanks, it was the initial issue and now I'm getting the output, but the Jenkins build is failing due to the attached error (Updated the question)

Comment: I see 2 options, first, search for Serializable xml parser in groovy or in Jenkins specifically, second use a method and annotate it with @NonCPS